# Content Scripts injected code errors do not show line numbers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a chrome extension that injects Content Scripts into tabs using `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`. However whenever I get an error from the injected JavaScript Chrome does not show me a line number or file from where the error throws. Also the error message is very plain.

Is it possible to get better feedback from chrome dev tools when injecting code?